# duplicate symbol of _main in Tesseract libtesseract_all.a(svpaint.o)

Tags: ios, duplicates, program-entry-point, tesseract, symbols

I've clone the project of "[iPhone-OCR-Tesseract-and-OpenCV](https://github.com/pablosproject/iPhone-OCR-Tesseract-and-OpenCV)" from Github, installed its pod, compiled files and it works great.

However, I try to merge the pod file with my existing one and compile it, I have an issue that shows

```
duplicate symbol _main in:
    /Users/ivanlin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MailTracker-duddjrlaosmnafgcbrqibnzstqws/Build/Intermediates/MailTracker.build/Debug-iphoneos/MailTracker.build/Objects-normal/armv7/main.o
    /Users/ivanlin/Documents/Projects/MailTracker/Pods/Tesseract/lib/libtesseract_all.a(svpaint.o) ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture armv7 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

It seems that there is another main function in the Tesseract library.

I am wondering why this issue does not show up in the original project.
I try to compare possible compile and link options between the original project and mine and there is no clue.

If anyone have experience to address this issue, please help a bit. I will very appreciate.

Many thanks.

Comment: do you have the source code of Tesseract library?

Comment: No. I just used the podfile of "iPhone-OCR-Tesseract-and-OpenCV" project. 

After executing "pod install", as you can see the content there are only all .h files and libtesseract_all.a in the folder.

Therefore, I cannot rename or move out the "main" function in the Tesseract to fix the issue.

But another question is that why "iPhone-OCR-Tesseract-and-OpenCV" project does not have such issue?

It also have a main.m in the Xcode project and also uses the same Tesseract library. Why does it not show such error? It is quite odd...

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question.

I've found the root cause and it is not relevant to re-including a main file.

After comparing "iPhone-OCR-Tesseract-and-OpenCV" and my own project, I found that my project has an additional linker option which is "load_all".

After removing out this "load_all" option, the issue is gone.

I am not sure why it cases the issue, but it is a solution in my case.